# Rendering group by queries on django admin interface. (distinct values on a field is broken in django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

There is a table datagen_crawlmeta with id as the primary key.
I want to get the distinct nm from the table and display it.

```
mysql> SELECT id, gid_id, nm from datagen_crawlmeta limit 10;
+----+--------+----------------------------+
| id | gid_id | nm                         |
+----+--------+----------------------------+
|  1 |      1 | votes                      |
|  2 |      1 | performance_rating         |
|  3 |      1 | title                      |
|  4 |      1 | specs__Sound__Loudspeaker  |
|  5 |      1 | specs__Sound__3.5mm jack   |
|  6 |      1 | specs__Sound__Alert types  |
|  7 |      1 | specs__Sound__unknown0     |
|  8 |      1 | specs__Features__Java      |
|  9 |      1 | specs__Features__Messaging |
| 10 |      1 | specs__Features__Colors    |
+----+--------+----------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Using the following code is returning all the rows.
Its because `self.model.objects.all().distinct('nm')` is returning CrawlMeta object and not the distinct nm.

I could use `self.model.objects.values_list('nm', flat=True).distinct()` but it returns
list of nm which is incompatible with the return type of queryset.

```
class CrawlMetaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['nm']

    def queryset(self, request):
        query_dict = request.GET
        nm = query_dict.get('nm')
        return self.model.objects.all().distinct('nm')
```

My final aim is to show the nm and count in the django admin interface using the
following query.

```
select nm, count(*) from datagen_crawlmeta group by nm;
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, instead of using

`self.model.objects.values_list('nm', flat=True).distinct()` and `self.model.objects.all().distinct('nm')`

use

`self.model.objects.values('nm').distinct()`.

Secondly, to write django equivalent of

`select nm, count(*) from datagen_crawlmeta group by nm;`

use

`self.model.objects.values('nm').annotate(count_nm=Count('nm')).values('nm','count_nm')`.

Now, using these you can manipulate the queryset function and get the two things displayed in your admin.